# Connect to SQL Server in local machine (host) from docker using host.docker.internal

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-network, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server instance running in my local computer using `host.docker.internal` (as recommended in https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

The `host.docker.internal` is successfully resolved to an IP, and it's ping-able

And I've opened up the port **1433** in my firewall configuration

**Error message**

> Connection refused 192.168.65.2:1433

**My connection string**

> Data Source=host.docker.internal,1433;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

**docker version**

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:12:48 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:22:38 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

**Docker for windows version**

[image: Docker for windows]

Comment: I updated the error message

Comment: but not the Data Source=

Comment: is it ping-able inside the container?

Comment: Yes I’ve tried it @vitr

Comment: is your SQL server accepting external connections in general? have you tried to connect to it not from the docker container, but, let's say from another machine in you network?

Comment: I figured out what's wrong, thanks for your help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If anyone have similar problem, here's how I solve it

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Enable TCP/IP in Server Network Configuration
- Restart SQL Service Service

[image: TCP/IP]

If it's still not working, there are a few more things to check

1. Firewall (open port 1433)
2. Enable remote connections to your sql server

[image]

Comment: In my case I had to do few additional steps, because I wanted to access SQL Server named instance on my host machine. Trying to access "host.docker.internal\SQLSERVER,1433" data source was always a failure.  

Eventually I've found solution that allows to connect to the named instance.  
1. Get the port of the named instance [How to do it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/)  
2. Enable firewall for the port you've found  
3. Change Data Source in connection string to: "host.docker.internal,<named_instance_port>"

Comment: Just wasted 2 hours on this connection issue, just to realize I forgot to restart the SQL Server service all this time ;( So glad I ran into this answer

Comment: Also check if the windows service SQL Server Browser is started

Comment: And use the connection string with host.docker.internal\\mssqlserver,1433